# Can you do a stencil glow with native GM:S commands?

Tags: game-maker, stencil

I am looking to a stencil glow on GM:S with d3d_* functions.

I could not find anything how to access the stencil buffer though.

Is it even possible to access the stencil buffer without using an external .dll?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible to access the stencil buffer using the native GameMaker API to D3D. The [API documentation](http://docs.yoyogames.com/) reveals that GameMaker exposes only a limited subset of the D3D API, more-or-less wrapped up in an easy-to-consume "immediate-mode" style.

There is no facility for accessing a stencil buffer in that API.